# NuxtJS Global Plugins: How to access from within a single file component? Unsubscribe from auth listener

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, nuxt.js

I am using NuxtJS and Firebase Auth for user authentication. I have the Auth observer set up like so in my `~/plugins/auth.js`:

```js
import { onAuthStateChanged, getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'

export default ({ store }) => {
  const auth = getAuth()
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
      // ...
    }
  })
}
```

I then have the plugin loaded in my `nuxt.config.js` like so:

```js
  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/firebase.js' },
    { src: '~/plugins/auth.js', mode: 'client' }
  ]
```

I assume that the above setup means that the Auth observer is going to run before every page is rendered?

I have a use-case where I need to "unsubscribe" from the observer when a new user signs up for an account on my app.

Is there a way I can get access to the auth observer in my sign-up page so I can unsubscribe from it?

Looking at [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onauthstatechanged) for the Auth observer, I think I simply need to call the observer again (it returns a function) like so:

`const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {//...})`, but how would I do that for the global onAuthStateChanged plugin I have?

Answer (score 2):

According to the NUXTJS [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins#inject-in-root--context), "Sometimes you want to make functions or values available across your app. You can inject those variables into Vue instances" . So, I set it up using the `inject()` method as described in the docs. Now I have access to the plugin in my SFCs using `this`.

**`~/plugins/auth.js`:**

```js
import { onAuthStateChanged, getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'
import { doc, getDoc } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { db } from '~/plugins/firebase'

export default ({ store }, inject) => {
  const auth = getAuth()
  inject(
    'authObserver',
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
      console.log('state:', user)
      if (user) {
        if (!user.emailVerified) {
          // Force logout user and reset store
          store.dispatch('logOutUser')
        } else {
          const { uid } = user
          const userDocRef = doc(db, 'users', uid)
          const userDocSnap = await getDoc(userDocRef)
          if (!userDocSnap.data().emailVerified) {
            await store.dispatch('updateUserProfile', user)
            store.dispatch('onAuthStateChangedAction', user)
          } else {
            store.dispatch('onAuthStateChangedAction', user)
          }
        }
      } else {
        store.dispatch('logOutUser')
      }
    })
  )
}
```

So now in my Sign Up page, I can reference the plugin like so:

**`/pages/sign-up/index.vue`:**

```js
data() {
  return {
    unsubscribe: null
  }
}

mounted() {
  this.unsubscribe = this.$authObserver // <---referencing auth plugin !
},

async signUp() {
  this.unsubscribe() // <-- detach auth listener here
  // TO DO: write sign up logic
```

Everything seems to work good. I don't know if this is the most efficent way to handle this use-case, but it works....

Answer (score 0):

This does not mean that it will be run before every page (a middleware is doing this) but rather it's available globally in your Nuxt app.
You indeed do have a `onAuthStateChanged` but this one is probably not updated everytime (not sure what this is doing exactly but I assume it's changing if you login/logout).

You will probably be able to find `onAuthStateChanged` on the Nuxt instance. You can do this to try to find it out in your client browser devtools. `$vm0` is basically `this` but in your devtools.

[image]

If it's not there, you may maybe look on the `window` object? Not sure where this one plugs into but it should be somewhere. The documentation does not give any info on this?

Also, you did pass on the [nuxt module](https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/) because it was lacking something or didn't want an extra dependency?

Comment: Typing `$vm0` in devtools gives me: `VM705:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $vm0 is not defined`

Comment: I passed on the Nuxt Firebase module because it does not use the newer Firebase SDK (v9 vs v8).

Comment: So I did the inject() method and it seems to work ....is that a viable solution for my case? I can post it as an update to my question if you prefer to see the details.

Comment: @redshift You need to select the `root` element in the devtools as shown in the screenshot. It works the same as the HTML elements selector. The `inject` method is probably totally viable. Please share some details just to be sure. :D

Comment: THanks @kissu. I added my answer above. Would love to get a second opinion on it from you.